# Tufte-book title page customization

Tags: graphics, titles, tufte

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}

    \title{Some stuff\\ \& \\Some other stuff}
    \author{Me}
    \date{Fall 2014}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

The title doesn't break into three lines; instead I get an error. Is there a way to fix this?

I also want to add an image to the cover. What's the best way? Do I need to redefine `\maketitle` (ugh), or is there something simpler?

Comment: Where should the image be inserted? Between author and title, before author, after title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the `\title`, `\author` and `\date` in the *preamble*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\titleimage}
\savebox{\titleimage}{\includegraphics[height=7\baselineskip]{example-image}}

\title[Some stuff \& Some other stuff]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  Some stuff \par \& \par Some other stuff \par \vspace{1cm}
  \usebox{\titleimage}}
\author{Me}
\date{Fall 2014}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Images should also be handled specially. Above I've placed the image in a box before including it in the `\title`.

Comment: That works. I'm wondering, though: in a simpler title situation (i.e., no line breaks within `\title`), I can set `\title`, `\author`, and `\date` within `document` and it works fine. Why do the line breaks change that?

Comment: @crmdgn: I can't do that without an error reporting that `\title` "Can be used only in preamble."

Comment: This is getting interesting. What might explain that difference?